# Manually URL linebreak with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls

First I should say that I don't have much experience with LaTeX.

I'm using BibLaTeX and Biber.

My Problem: I have a (justified) bibliography with long URL's containing long words. BibLaTeX makes a linebreak at a place with a slash. But I want to make that linebreak in the following word.

In the minimal example: I want to do the linebreak at: Markt-beobachtung.

The aim is that in the second line there aren't that big spaces between the letters, words, slashes. And that the second line doesn't start with `//`.

I'm trying to do this for 3 hours now, so I really appreciate your help.

Here is the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\bibliography{test_bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{bundesnetzagentur}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And that's the `test_bib.bib`:

```
@ONLINE{bundesnetzagentur,
author = {Bundesnetzagentur},
title = {Teilnehmerentwicklung im Mobilfunk},
year = {2012},
url = {http://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Sachgebiete/Telekommunikation/Marktbeobachtung/Mobilfunkteilnehmer/Mobilfunkteilnehmer_node.html },
hyphenation=ngerman
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 10):

The package `biblatex` loads the package [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url). The list of characters that allow line-breaks is given by `\UrlBreaks` and `\UrlBigBreaks`, which have the format `\do\c` for each character `c`. For more information read the documentation.

The default setting of `\UrlBreaks` is

```
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\.\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
  \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
\def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do@url@hyp}%
```

To allow more break points you can add

```
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}
```

for ordinary symbols and you can do

```
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{%
  \do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f%
  \do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m%
  \do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z%
  \do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G%
  \do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U%
  \do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}
```

for breakpoints after letters.

In the same way you can setup the command `\UrlNoBreaks` to define symbols/letters where no linebreaks are allowed. The default setting is:

```
\def\UrlNoBreaks{\do\(\do\[\do\{\do\<}%
```

---

The commands using the special symbol `@`. So you need `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`. Please refer the question [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/5764) for more information.

Comment: OK with that commands I can set the characters which allow a linebreak. But I want to set the linebreak manually.      I tried your suggestion. But it makes a linebreak at a bad place. It's doing: Ma \linebreak rktbeobachtung

Comment: Is there some way to have this only operate on one url? I tried giving the default `\def\UrlBreaks`, again, but it had no effect.

Comment: You can add to the bib entry you are interested in modifying the field `Execute = {\def\UrlBreaks{}}` or whatever modification to the `url` package you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great, but if you want to do it manually, then you can do it manually:

```
@online{bundesnetzagentur,
author = {Bundesnetzagentur},
title = {Teilnehmerentwicklung im Mobilfunk},
year = "2012",
addendum = "\texttt{\href{http://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Sachgebiete/Telekommunikation/Marktbeobachtung/Mobilfunkteilnehmer/Mobilfunkteilnehmer_node.html}{http://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/DE/Sachgebiete/Telekommunikation/Markt\\beobachtung/Mobilfunkteilnehmer/Mobilfunkteilnehmer\_node.html}}",
hyphenation=ngerman
}
```

Note that:

1. It requires loading `hyperref` package in the preamble of the document.
2. In the text part of `href`, `_` needs to be replaced by `\_` to avoid errors.

If you don't necessarily want a hyperlink, you can remove `\href` and the first group in curly brackets, and then you don't need to load the `hyperref` package.

Something similar can be done with doi addresses too, for example:

```
addendum = "doi:\href{https://doi.org/10.1023/B:MOON.0000031922.78588.6d}{10.1023/B:MOON.0000031922.785\\88.6d}"
```

Comment: It is easier to just load `xurl` and just USE `\url{URL} `. In `xurl` the url is alloto line break at any char.