# Long Hyperlinks in Tex

Tags: hyperref

I am having again a problem with too long hyperlinks. The code will be generated automatically. Thats why it is almost impossible to correct it manually, as the document will be too long.

Basically the problem is the jusitification of hyperlink in second line in attached picture. Is there a way out to this problem?

Thanks alot!!!

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces,spaces,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{plainpages = false, colorlinks, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, hypertexnames = false, bookmarksopen = true, bookmarksopenlevel = 0, bookmarksdepth = 10}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[H]
 \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
 \begin{picture}(7,22.7456)
 \put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.1666]{can_PDFs/00000000002_CANScalings.pdf}}
 \end{picture}
 \caption{\protect\path{can/CAN_Scalings}}
 \label{can/CANScalings}
 \end{figure}

 {\large Children:}     \hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungACLNXCOGACLNLNRWDTRWDTACLNVEHLNZwei]{\protect\path {Skalierung_ACLNX_COG__ACLN_LN_RWDT__RWDT_ACLN_VEH_LN2}};
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungACLNYCOG]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ACLNY_COG}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLBRTORQSUMAVLBRTORQSUMDVCH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_BRTORQ_SUM__AVL_BRTORQ_SUM_DVCH}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLFORCBRKFA]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_FORC_BRKFA}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLHVEKKAVLULINK]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_HV_EKK__AVL_U_LINK}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLLOGRRW]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_LOGR_RW}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLSTEAFTAXWHL]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_STEA_FTAX_WHL}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPHR]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_HR}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLRPMWHLFLHAVLRPMWHLFRHAVLRPMWHLRLHAVLRPMWHLRRHNRadZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_RPM_WHL_FLH__AVL_RPM_WHL_FRH__AVL_RPM_WHL_RLH__AVL_RPM_WHL_RRH__N_Rad2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungCHGNGENBEins]{\protect\path{Skalierung_CHGNG_ENB1}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPDATEDAY]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_DATE_DAY}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPDATEWDAY]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_DATE_WDAY}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPMN]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_MN}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPSEC]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_SEC}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTA]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungIDZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ID2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPPOGRBTARPOGRBTRGGPOGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_PO_GRB__TAR_PO_GRB__TRGG_PO_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDVCOVEHSTVEHDVCODRVDIRVEHUCNFRDRVDIRVEHCFD]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DVCO_VEH__ST_VEH_DVCO__DRVDIR_VEH_UCNFR__DRVDIR_VEH_CFD}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTALH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA_LH}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTARH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA_RH}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMASSVEH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MASS_VEH}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungGangSTGRSELGRBSTGRSELGRBSBWSTGRSELDRVSTGRSELGRBVRFDSTGRDTKickout]{\protect\path{Skalierung_Gang__ST_GRSEL_GRB__ST_GRSEL_GRB_SBW__ST_GRSEL_DRV__ST_GRSEL_GRB_VRFD__ST_GRDT_Kickout}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungIDOBDSENERROBDSENEinsERROBDSENZweiRWDTOBDSENEinsRWDTOBDSENZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ID_OBD_SEN__ERR_OBD_SEN_1__ERR_OBD_SEN_2__RWDT_OBD_SEN_1__RWDT_OBD_SEN_2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMDMOTEFF]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MD_MOT_EFF}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMILEKM]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MILE_KM}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRELLUFTMASSE]{\protect\path{Skalierung_REL_LUFTMASSE}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungQUTARWMOMPTSUMRECUP]{\protect\path{Skalierung_QU_TAR_WMOM_PT_SUM_RECUP}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRQCOOLGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RQ_COOL_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRQHTFLAIC]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RQ_HTFL_AIC}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRWDTBLS]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RWDT_BLS}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSTCCLTGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ST_CCLT_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSLIPRELFTAXBAX]{\protect\path{Skalierung_SLIP_REL_FTAX_BAX}}; 
\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSTGRBECUKickoutZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ST_GRB_ECU_Kickout2}}; 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the white space before each link to be an indent. You can set the indentation to 0pt temporarily.

Comment: Answer to (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/manually-url-linebreak-with-biblatex) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I must confess to not being sure what the hyperrefs represent and hence not being sure how to best typeset them. Typesetting each one on a separate line, with `\parindent` set to zero, might be a step in the right direction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces,spaces,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{plainpages = false, 
    colorlinks, linkcolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, 
    hypertexnames = false, bookmarksopen = true,    
    bookmarksopenlevel = 0, bookmarksdepth = 10}
 \begin{document}

%%% commented out because no access to the image file
% \begin{figure}[H]
% \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
% \begin{picture}(7,22.7456)
% \put(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.1666]{can_PDFs/00000000002_CANScalings.pdf}}
% \end{picture}
% \caption{\protect\path{can/CAN_Scalings}}
% \label{can/CANScalings}
% \end{figure}

\begingroup % keep reset of \parindent parameter local
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
{\large Children:}    

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungACLNXCOGACLNLNRWDTRWDTACLNVEHLNZwei]{\protect\path {Skalierung_ACLNX_COG__ACLN_LN_RWDT__RWDT_ACLN_VEH_LN2}};

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungACLNYCOG]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ACLNY_COG}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLBRTORQSUMAVLBRTORQSUMDVCH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_BRTORQ_SUM__AVL_BRTORQ_SUM_DVCH}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLFORCBRKFA]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_FORC_BRKFA}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLHVEKKAVLULINK]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_HV_EKK__AVL_U_LINK}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLLOGRRW]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_LOGR_RW}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLSTEAFTAXWHL]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_STEA_FTAX_WHL}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPHR]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_HR}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungAVLRPMWHLFLHAVLRPMWHLFRHAVLRPMWHLRLHAVLRPMWHLRRHNRadZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_AVL_RPM_WHL_FLH__AVL_RPM_WHL_FRH__AVL_RPM_WHL_RLH__AVL_RPM_WHL_RRH__N_Rad2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungCHGNGENBEins]{\protect\path{Skalierung_CHGNG_ENB1}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPDATEDAY]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_DATE_DAY}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPDATEWDAY]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_DATE_WDAY}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPMN]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_MN}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPSEC]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_SEC}};

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTA]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungIDZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ID2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDISPPOGRBTARPOGRBTRGGPOGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DISP_PO_GRB__TAR_PO_GRB__TRGG_PO_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungDVCOVEHSTVEHDVCODRVDIRVEHUCNFRDRVDIRVEHCFD]{\protect\path{Skalierung_DVCO_VEH__ST_VEH_DVCO__DRVDIR_VEH_UCNFR__DRVDIR_VEH_CFD}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTALH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA_LH}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungFLLVFUTARH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_FLLV_FUTA_RH}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMASSVEH]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MASS_VEH}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungGangSTGRSELGRBSTGRSELGRBSBWSTGRSELDRVSTGRSELGRBVRFDSTGRDTKickout]{\protect\path{Skalierung_Gang__ST_GRSEL_GRB__ST_GRSEL_GRB_SBW__ST_GRSEL_DRV__ST_GRSEL_GRB_VRFD__ST_GRDT_Kickout}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungIDOBDSENERROBDSENEinsERROBDSENZweiRWDTOBDSENEinsRWDTOBDSENZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ID_OBD_SEN__ERR_OBD_SEN_1__ERR_OBD_SEN_2__RWDT_OBD_SEN_1__RWDT_OBD_SEN_2}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMDMOTEFF]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MD_MOT_EFF}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungMILEKM]{\protect\path{Skalierung_MILE_KM}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRELLUFTMASSE]{\protect\path{Skalierung_REL_LUFTMASSE}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungQUTARWMOMPTSUMRECUP]{\protect\path{Skalierung_QU_TAR_WMOM_PT_SUM_RECUP}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRQCOOLGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RQ_COOL_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRQHTFLAIC]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RQ_HTFL_AIC}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungRWDTBLS]{\protect\path{Skalierung_RWDT_BLS}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSTCCLTGRB]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ST_CCLT_GRB}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSLIPRELFTAXBAX]{\protect\path{Skalierung_SLIP_REL_FTAX_BAX}}; 

\hyperref[can/CANScalings/SkalierungSTGRBECUKickoutZwei]{\protect\path{Skalierung_ST_GRB_ECU_Kickout2}}; 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```