# Problem bibtex url slash

Tags: bibtex

In my .bib archive I have the next reference:

```
@misc{Quora,
    title = {In optimization, why is Newton's method much faster than gradient descent?},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.quora.com/In-optimization-why-is-Newtons-method-much-faster-than-gradient-descent/}},
    note = {Accessed: 2015-06-07},
    author = {Carlin Eng}
}
```

and the result in the pdf is

[image]

I suppose that is for the long url "In-optimization-why-is-Newtons-method-much-faster-than-gradient-descent/" without any slashes.

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`

Comment: You will have to add the dash `-` as a allowable linebreak point.  See, for example, the answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/manually-url-linebreak-with-biblatex and the macros `\UrlBreaks` and `\UrlBigBreaks`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler with `biblatex`, and its `url` and `urlseen` fields:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{urltest.bib}
@misc{Quora,
title = {In optimization, why is Newton's method much faster than gradient descent?},
url = {https://www.quora.com/In-optimization-why-is-Newtons-method-much-faster-than-gradient-descent/},
urldate = {2015-06-07},
author = {Carlin Eng}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend = biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
urlseen = {accessed on}
}
\addbibresource{urltest.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]