# Unable to get break lines in URLs for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

I cannot get the URL address in a reference in my document to break. I looked at this question's chosen answer [URLs in bibliography: LaTeX not breaking line as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected) and it did not work for me.

The citation at "14" hangs over the right edge of left column boundary

MWE:

tex file

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage{parskip}
% commented for existing packages in cls
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[lined, boxed, commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}

\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 21mu
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{IEEEabrv,reference}
```

bib file entry not breaking

```
@Manual{nmonchart,
title={nmonchart},
author = "Griffiths, Nigel",
address={http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php?n=Site.Nmonchart},
}
```

I have to edit the link because of protocol

Screenshot of the paper currently

[image]

Comment: This? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102673/manually-url-linebreak-with-biblatex/102697#102697

Comment: Off-topic: the `subfigure` is deprecated and conflicts with the `caption` package. Don't use `subfigure`; instead, employ either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Comment: @Erwann - The OP's fundamental error is related to an improper field name for the URL string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in your bib entry: The name of the field that contains the entry's URL address should be `url`, not `address`:

```
@Manual{nmonchart,
  title  = {nmonchart},
  author = "Griffiths, Nigel",
  url    = {http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php?n=Site.Nmonchart},
}
```

Second, load the `xurl` package rather than the `url` package to allow linebreaking in long URL strings anywhere.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
%% (I simplified the preamble to make it truly minimal)

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@Manual{nmonchart,
  title  = {nmonchart},
  author = "Griffiths, Nigel",
  url    = {http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php?n=Site.Nmonchart},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xurl} % not \usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 21mu % not needed when using 'xurl' package

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```